# Enabled Surveys, but cannot find Surveys tab, how do I find them?

Tags: survey

Enabled Surveys, but cannot find Surveys tab, how do I find them?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open Survey tab, simply follow `/0Kd` link and that will open survey tab if this is not shown.

Sometimes it might take some time for Salesforce to update the available tab list